# Can a JPA Entity with @Transient field store data from SQL query ResultSet?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

Example:

```
@Entity
class Table_A{
    @Id
    @generatedValue
    private long ID;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Transient
    private String otherName;

    // getters and setters

    public long getID()
    { return ID;}
    public void setID(long ID)
    { this.ID = ID;}

     public String getName()
    { return Name;}
    public void setName(String name)
    { this.name = name;}

    public String getOtherName()
    { return otherName;}
    public void setOtherName(String otherName)
    { this.otherName = otherName;}
}
```

Query Example:

```
String sql = "SELECT Table_A.*, otherName 
FROM Table_A INNER JOIN Other_Table ON Table_A.id = Other_Table.id";

List<Table_A> = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Table_A.class).getResultList();
```

**NOTE:**

"otherName" column is a field of Other_Table.

Other_Table is not an Entity

**PROBLEM:**

the problem is, I can't store the "otherName" column result to the @Transient field of the Table_A entity. Is there any way of doing this? It always returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've used the form of [createNativeQuery](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) that expects to be able to place the result directly into your class `Table_A` - but of course the `otherName` won't map.

If you use the other form of [createNativeQuery](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), that uses a named `@SqlResultSetMapping`, you *might* be able to get the value of `otherName` into a `@ColumnResult` that you can use. Have a look at [the example here](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/ColumnResult).

I'm afraid you'll still probably have to manually call `setOtherName()` at some point though :-(

Comment: please give me an example, like the query above, I dont know where the "@ColumnResult" would be set, where to attach the "@SQLResultSetMapping", how to use it etc. help me millhouse.

Comment: YEs!!!, Yeehaaahh! , I'VE DONE IT... after a global search on google, this article helps me a lot, (traversing SQLResultSetMapping) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927836/jpa-setting-entity-class-property-from-calculated-column. though not related to the problem, this is a great alternative! thank you millhouse.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. But the fix is obvious: map the `Other_Table` to an entity, and introduce an association between both entities. Being forced to use transient fields and SQL queries is most of the time a sign of an incorrect JPA design. Don't fight with JPA. Use it the way it's intended to be used, and everything will be much easier.

Comment: nooo, I do not have control to that other_table since it is integrated within LIFERAY, not within my application :((

Comment: So what. If you're able to query it using SQL, why wouldn't you be able to query it using JPA?

Comment: give me an example please, i'm a newbie in JPA. :D

Comment: The reference documentation is full of well-explained examples. Read it. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/

Comment: Yeah, I'll agree. It is the sign of an incorrect JPA design. JPA is designed incorrect. You shouldn't have to write convoluted code that does who knows what behind the scenes just to add a column from another table into your result set. Dogma kills.